# Okta Java/Spring API generating ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, okta

I'm trying to connect my local Okta server to a Spring Boot application, but I'm getting "The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)'
```

" error

I've tried connect my local Okta server to a Spring Boot application, but a more detailed error is being thrown when trying to add Okta ApiClient to my Spring service:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClientBuilder.requestFactory(DefaultClientBuilder.java:471)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)'

The calling method's class, com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClientBuilder, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/filipe-lima/.m2/repository/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/10.3.0/okta-sdk-impl-10.3.0.jar!/com/okta/sdk/impl/client/DefaultClientBuilder.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/filipe-lima/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.8/spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.8/spring-web-6.0.8.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClientBuilder and org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
```

In my pom.xml there's the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cision</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>okta-spring-integration</name>
    <description>Okta Proof of Concept for Spring App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-sdk-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-sdk-impl</artifactId>
            <version>10.3.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Already tried to update HttpClient libs on POM, change Okta-SDK versions, and even looked at [Okta SDK Java Github Repository](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java/issues/794), but still got no success.

Answer (score 2):

Please use okta-sdk-api version 8.2.3 or lower, the 10.x version of the SDK has breaking changes which are not fully compatible with okta-spring-boot 3.0.3 yet.